# Pip version in virtualenv

Tags: python, pip, virtualenv

**Edit**:

The problem was that i had `virtualenv==1.9` installed which is a broken version. Before you try to debug anything i suggest you upgrade your packages ;-)

**Original**:

Im haveing a problem with pip and (probably) openssl found [here](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/829). The easy workaround is to downgrad pip to 1.2.1. This works but every time i create a virtual environment with virtualenv it installs pip 1.5.6 the current version of pip. The same happens if you install djangocms-installer, so every time i install something with dependencies to pip i have to check/set the pip version again.

Is there a way to set the pip version for virtualenv?

Is there a way to set a 'default' version for a program for every installation of this program?

Edit:

OS: Mac os 10.7.5

Python: 2.7

Comment: Great, give me a second and I'll teach you how to debug this.

Comment: Try playing with symlinks, it's a bodge I'll admit.. but it works

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're having a problem because you're downgrading `pip`, but likely not changing `virtualenv`'s behavior of installing the default `pip`.  How would you go about debugging this?

1. Find which `virtualenv` script  is being called:

   ```
   [~] type -a virtualenv                                                                                                                           
   virtualenv is an alias for virtualenv --no-site-packages
   virtualenv is /usr/local/bin/virtualenv
   ```
2. Get some information from `virtualenv`:

   ```
   [~] head -n5 /usr/local/bin/virtualenv                                                                                                          
   #!/usr/local/opt/python/bin/python2.7
   # EASY-INSTALL-ENTRY-SCRIPT: 'virtualenv==1.11.5','console_scripts','virtualenv'
   __requires__ = 'virtualenv==1.11.5'
   import sys
   from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
   ```

Now we know that `virtualenv` is using the Python 2.7 install located at `/usr/local/opt/python/bin`.

3. While you can follow the import path around, it's easy enough to just look in the directory we found in #2 to see which `pip` will get called:

   ```
   [~] ls /usr/local/opt/python/bin | grep pip                                                                                                          
   pip
   pip2
   pip2.7
   ```

and ask `pip` to give you its version:

```
    [~] /usr/local/opt/python/bin/pip -V                                                                                                        
    pip 1.5.6 from /usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.8/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-        packages/pip-1.5.6-py2.7.egg (python 2.7)
```

That's why!

While I'd **strongly** advise fixing your SSL issue instead of downgrading `pip`, you have some options:

A. Downgrade the version of `pip` "globally" in the locations found in step 3.  If you look in `/usr/local/bin/pip`, you'll see the following:

```
    #!/usr/local/opt/python/bin/python2.7
    # EASY-INSTALL-ENTRY-SCRIPT: 'pip==1.5.6','console_scripts','pip'
    __requires__ = 'pip==1.5.6'
    import sys
    from pkg_resources import load_entry_point

    if __name__ == '__main__':
        sys.exit(
            load_entry_point('pip==1.5.6', 'console_scripts', 'pip')()
        )
```

If you have an older version of `pip` in your Python path (e.g.), you should be able to substitute the version on the `__requires__` and `load_entry_point(...` lines.

B. Tell `virtualenv` not to install `pip` by  by specifying the `--no-pip` flag when creating a `virtualenv`.  You will then be responsible for putting your desired `pip` files into the virtual environments `bin` and `lib` folders.

C. Downgrade `pip` everywhere.  When you installed the older version of `pip`, it either ended up in the wrong directory or was not the first `pip` found by Python when going through the `virtualenv` setup.  Be careful to call the same Python interpreter that `virtualenv` is calling.

(also note that you could "trick" the virtual environment by editing the `activate` script, but you'd be a braver person than I.)

Comment: thanks for the answer. i wanst able to follow your debug guide because my virtual env gets python from the Libraries folder. atm i have to do some work but ill try to find this pip easy-install-entry-script
much apprechiated

Comment: No problem.  The paths aren't expected to be the same.

Comment: i managed to find a solution to the ssl problem, but i still get 1.5.6 pip in my virtualenvs ;-)

Edit: if anyone has the same ssl problem check if you use virtualenv 1.9, if you do so you have to update it